# Overwriting library file causes segmentation fault

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

After I have the executable file running I overwrite its .so library file with a new version and this causes the executable to die with segmentation fault. I thought the library file is being accessed only when ELF file is loaded. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The library file is mapped into the memory when it is loaded (usually, when the executable is loaded - but libraries can also be loaded later with `dlopen()`).  The actual pages of the file are then demand-loaded as required.

Overwriting the file will cause pages from the file mapped `MAP_SHARED` (which is most of them) to be updated with the new contents.  This is what causes the segmentation faults.  Don't do that - instead, remove the existing .so file, then write the new one in its place.

Answer (score 2):

Like caf said, it's not a good idea to overwrite an executable while it's running.

Instead, write the new files as a temporary file in the same directory, then rename it atomically with rename(). This is what installers typically do.